# GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.import failed with error: Invalid iCalUID value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a script that imports Office events from the team members' private calendar to a team calendar. This mostly works perfectly fine. But in some cases I get the following error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to the calendar. events. import failed with error: Invalid iCalUID value.

In the cases where it **succeeds**, the event has the following values:

- id: 'abcd1234'
- iCalUID: 'abcd1234@google.com'

In the cases where it **fails**, the event has the following values:

- id: 'abcd1234_20230213T161500Z'
- iCalUID: 'abcd1234@google.com'

Otherwise, I see no difference in the event.

The code I use to import the event is:

```
Calendar.Events.import(event, calendarId);
```

Has somebody an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Does it also happens when running under the "Try it" tool here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/import

Comment: I can't really test it there...

Answer (score 1):

**Calendar API**

Recurring events and how they are handled under the API would be different due to certain parameters needed or required to be considered.

The main reason it would fail is because the iCalUID is unique, the recurring events would have the `RFC3339` that is linked to the dates of that particular event as an extra "id", which is in your example the:

> 20230213T161500Z

That is why the error would occur, if you do a `get` of just the iCalUID, you would find just the first portion, not the "id" portion with the date information. I managed  to generate a sample by running a test under the "Try it" and found out what are the parameters that are required:

[image]

I notice that you need to make sure to provide the `RRULE` with the field of `recurrence`. It would need the end and start fields information for the times in order for the import to work properly.

Based on your sample code, it would need to have more parameters, similar to this:

```
Calendar.Events.import(event, calendarId, recurrence, start, end);
```

That way you would be providing the necessary data for the API, to replicate and import the recurring event.

**References:**

- https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/import
- https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, but I don't know the RRULE of the events...